# Integrating large PostgreSQL table as partition for a new table

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I currently have a relatively large table containing timeseries data (628+ mil. live rows). The table definition (some names changed slightly) at the bottom of question.

I want to attach the existing table as a partition to a new (partitioned) table. However, the existing table has a singular `id` primary key (mainly used because Django requires it). Attaching the table would require me to update the primary key constraint to `(id, timestamp)` on the old table.

Because `id` is unique this isn't an issue, but given the size of the table I wonder if this constraint is checked upon creation (leading to quite the query) or whether only newly added/updated rows are checked. Stopping read/writes to the table for a few minutes is possible, but I can't wait for multiple hours.

---

### Intended new table

Like the old table the `id` column is mainly required by our ORM sadly. A similar `(prop_id, "timestamp", value)` index would be used on the partitioned table as well.

```
CREATE TABLE "newtable" (
    "id"            bigserial NOT NULL,
    "timestamp"     timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "prop_id"       integer NOT NULL,
    "value"         double precision NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id", "timestamp")
) PARTITION BY RANGE ("timestamp")
;
```

---

### Old table definition

The `"id"` primary key is an artifact of our ORM (Django) and is inconsequential for any queries we do. We use the `(prop_id, "timestamp", value)` index 99.9% of the time for index-only scans.

```
  Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                         Default                     | Storage | Stats target | Description
-----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id        | bigint                   |           | not null | nextval('tablename_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              |
 timestamp | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                     | plain   |              |
 value     | double precision         |           | not null |                     | plain   |              |
 prop_id   | integer                  |           | not null |                     | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "tablename_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "tablename_prop_id_timestamp_value_b9bc8326_idx" btree (prop_id, "timestamp", value)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "tablename_prop_id_67f339b0_fk_othertable" FOREIGN KEY (prop_id) REFERENCES othertable(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: Will the large partition become obsolete at some point? Do you need foreign key constraints pointing to the partitioned table?

Comment: Yes, the old table will be deleted after a few months. The foreign key contraints are pointing to a sensor definition table which contains more data about the specific timeseries and are required.

Comment: To clarify: a foreign key will be added to `prop_id` similar like the old table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proceed like this:

- Don't create a primary key constraint on the partitioned table for now.
  Rather, create unique indexes on the new partitions that will later become partitions of the primary key index.
- As soon as the large table is old enough that you don't need the data any more, drop it.
- Then you can create a primary key on the partitioned table that will use the already existing unique indexes as partitions.